# I have a few questions when I am finding a point on line intersection of two planes

Tags: vectors

When we are finding a point on line intersection of two planes, I want to know why we have to let z = 0 in stead of letting x or y.

Why are we using the equations of that two planes instead of using the equation of the line intersection?

Thank you for any help from you guys!

Comment: Firstly you don't need to put $z=0$ necessarily. Secondly if you already have the line of intersection then finding points on that line should be straightforward, surely?

Comment: What do you think would be "the equation of the line intersection" ?

Comment: You'll probably need more equations to give the full story. When you do, please use this to show them correctly: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1):

To get the line of intersection of two planes, you need to find the vector direction $D$ of the line, and some specific point $P$ on the line.

Getting the direction vector $D$ is easy — you simply compute the cross product of the two plane normals.

To get a point $P$ on the line of intersection, there are many possible approaches. One approach is to find the lines where each plane intersects the plane $z=0$. This is essentially what you’re doing when you set $z=0$ in the two plane equations. Then you intersect the two lines to get a point $P$.

In this technique, there’s nothing special about the plane $z=0$. You could just as well use the plane $x=0$ or the plane $y=0$, or (almost) any other plane. For this to work, the plane you use must not be parallel to the direction vector $D$. So, in fact, sometimes using the plane $z=0$ won’t work. If it doesn’t, use $x=0$ or $y=0$ instead — one of the three choices is guaranteed to work. If you want to avoid this trial-and-error process, the safest choice is to use the plane through the origin with normal $D$, but this makes the algebra a bit harder.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107156/a-point-on-the-line-of-intersection-of-two-planes?rq=1) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245827/the-line-of-intersection-of-two-planes?rq=1).

Comment: So to find a point of the line, you need to find a point on the line...

Comment: Can you tell me more about using the plane through the origin with normal D? Likes some steps

Comment: If $D=(a,b,c)$ then this plane has equation $ax+by+cz=0$. Now you have three planes, and you can find their point of intersection. You do this by solving three equations in the three unknowns $x, y,z$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The intersection of two planes is an infinite set. To get a single point, you need an additional condition. A convenient way is to add the equation of an arbitrary plane, such as $z=0$ (but this plane must not be parallel to the intersection).
2. The implicit equation of a line is precisely a system of two plane equations. Another representation of a line uses a known point on the line, but that is what you are after !